# Add text after grep:ing a word with BASH

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep

I have a file like this:

```
$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
]

$password = [
   'aokroae',
   '43t03it0i0i',
   '430it935ti',
]
```

I need to create a bash script which greps e.g "$account = [" and adds the new user at the end of the row within the $account. 
Which would be the best way to do this?

So, if I wanted to add the user "Michael" via a bash script, the expected output would then be for the $account:

```
$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
   'Michael',
]
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: Updated the question so it should be more clear.

Comment: Is the order of the user list important, or would it be okay to insert the new user at the top of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using awk

This adds Michael to the end of the list:

```
awk '/^[$]account/,/]/{ if (/]/) {print "   '\''Michael'\'',";}} 1' file
$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
   'Michael',
]

$password = [
   'aokroae',
   '43t03it0i0i',
   '430it935ti',
]
```

#### How it works

- `/^[$]account/, /]/`

  This defines a range of lines starting with `$account` and ending with `]`
- `if (/]/) {print "   '\''Michael'\'',";}`

  For lines in the range, if the line contains `]`, then add Michael.
- `1`

  This is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

### Using sed

```
$ sed "/^[$]account/,/]/ { /]/ s/^/   'Michael',\n/}" file
$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
   'Michael',
]

$password = [
   'aokroae',
   '43t03it0i0i',
   '430it935ti',
]
```

#### How it works

The logic here is quite similar to that used in the awk code:

- `/^[$]account/,/]/`

  This defines a range of lines starting with `$account` and ending with `]`
- `{ /]/ s/^/   'Michael',\n/}`

  For the lines in the range, this tests to see if the line contains `]`.  If so, then Michael is substituted in at the beginning of the line.

  We don't need to tell sed explicitly the it should  print the line.  sed does this by default.

Comment: Thank you! The other answers were good too but your answer described how awk and sed were used.

Answer (score 2):

If you could add the information to the beginning of the list, it would be easier:

```
sed -e "/\$account = \[/a\ \ \ 'newuser',"
```

`a` just adds a new line after the one that matched.

To add it to the end, you can use sed, too:

```
sed -e '/[$]account = \[/bi;b;:i {n;/\]/{i \   '\'newuser\',$'\nb};bi}'
```

Explanation:

- `bi` branches to the label `i` if `$account` is matched.
- otherwise, `b` just starts processing the next line.
- the `i` label introduces a block that reads the next line (`n`), if it finds `]`, it inserts (`i`) the new value and starts processing the next line normally (`b`).
- otherwise, the `i` block processes the next line (`bi`).

Answer (score 1):

```
# Variable assignation for generic use
Section="account"
Value="NewUser"

# value integration in section
sed "
# filter to only good section (just print for others)
/^[$]${Section} = \\[/,/]/ !b

# To add at begin
   /^[$]${Section} = \\[/ a\\
   '${Value}'
# To add at the end
   /]/ i\\
   '${Value}'

    " YourFile
```

- select the part of code if you prefer at begin or end of the section (comment the 2 following line or delete them)
- same code to add in different section
- don't forget that *Section* value is a regex value
- it use the `i\` and `a\` for insert and append a line of text (the next line) and filter to select the good part of text to apply

Answer (score 1):

simplest thing to do is keep the previous line and then replace it's text with the new text when necessary so you retain indentation:

```
$ awk -v srch='$account' -v add='Michael' '
    $1 == srch { f = 1 }
    f && /]/ { sub(/[^\047[:space:]]+/,add,prev); print prev; f = 0 }
    { print; prev = $0 }
' file
$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
   'Michael',
]

$password = [
   'aokroae',
   '43t03it0i0i',
   '430it935ti',
]
```

The above will work in any awk and will always indent the added text so it lines up with the preceding line, no hard-coding of indentation necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this gnu-awk:

```
awk -v sq="'" -v RS='\\]\n' '/account =/{$0 = $0 "   " sq "Michael" sq "," ORS }
     {printf $0 RT}' file

$account = [
   'user1',
   'anotheruser1',
   'companyaccount',
   'Michael',
]

$password = [
   'aokroae',
   '43t03it0i0i',
   '430it935ti',
]
```